# How can I make each section fit within the li box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGxKoO

I have this and I'm wondering how I can automate the content within each li not going over to the next li column. Am I missing any CSS that would prevent this behavior?

Currently, the Home content goes over to Contact (the A's do). I've thought I could use javascript to insert a break after a set number of character in each section or just use manually a br tag in the html before it overflows.

Here is the CSS :

```
  li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  color: green;

}
section {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you have an artificially created situation that would never appear in the real world.

Comment: This is about functionality, the code itself works fine. Also, this problem most likely does appear in the world not necessarily within this exact context but enough to where they have implemented the CSS word-wrap. I appreciate you trying to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  color: green;

}
    section {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
      word-wrap: break-word;

    }
```

Added `word-wrap: break-word;` for section.

Seems to work fine!